# Key Generation/Storage for react-native apps to encrypt realm db

Tags: encryption, react-native, realm

Does realm have any react-native support for key generation/key storage for encrypting the realm db? I wanted to check with the team working on realm before writing any native modules for the same. If there is any node module support for react native, that would be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Realm does not provide any APIs for the generation or storage of encryption keys. I'm copying a comment I made in the past on this issue below just to provide my thoughts on some considerations that should be taken when dealing with encrypting Realms on React Native…

The [react-native-keychain](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-keychain) module only supports password strings, whereas Realm expects a 512-bit (64-byte) data blob as either an `ArrayBuffer` or `ArrayBufferView` (e.g. `Uint8Array`, et al).

If you're randomly generating a password, then I would suggest base64-encoding that data into a string before storing with `react-native-keychain`, then base64 decoding it when you get it out. I'd recommend checking out [base64-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/base64-js) for dealing with raw data (`atob`/`btoa` only deals in strings).

On the other hand, if the user is providing a password, then you can store that directly in the keychain and use a 512-bit hash of that password as the encryption key. A SHA-512 hash would accomplish that, but typically with encryption you want to use a hashing algorithm that includes a salt and is fundamentally slow, thus making it much harder to brute force. The standard for doing this is [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2), though newer and better hashing methods exist. I'd recommend checking out [crypto-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js) or [pbkdf2-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pbkdf2-js) for this.

Comment: Thanks for the react native library links, Scott. All the points mentioned are very informative.

Comment: Scott,  I have decided to write my own native module and expose the key via the bridge to the react-native module. I was looking at this example - https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/feature/example/store_password/examples/StoreEncryptionPassword/src/main/java/realm/io/storeencryptionpassword/Store.java. If I expose  generateKeyForRealm( ), for instance, from the example above, will the encryption for realm work? I just want to see if I understood your 512-bit comment there

Comment: Yes, the `generateKeyForRealm()` method there is just returning a completely random 64-byte (512-bit) key.

Comment: Thanks much, Scott!

Answer (score 0):

To expand a little on this. You can use a site like https://asecuritysite.com/encryption/PBKDF2z to generate a 64 byte hash as both a hex string and a base64 string.

You can use the hex string in the Realm Browser GUI to unlock the realm file. You can use the base64 string with the [base64-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/base64-js) library mentioned above. Just pass the base64 string into base64js.toByteArray() and that is the key you would use in new Realm({encryptionKey: key...})