# How to Encrypt Realm in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, encryption, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I am trying to encrypt Realm on my React native app using the PIN user sets for the app after loging in.

User logs into the app and then sets a PIN which user is going to use for the following interactions with the app. I want to use this PIN as the encryption key.

I have looked at examples on 
https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/#encryption
[Key Generation/Storage for react-native apps to encrypt realm db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38059913/key-generation-storage-for-react-native-apps-to-encrypt-realm-db)

Got an idea that I need to add the encryption key at the point of opening the database but how can I pass key to the database options. if you can suggest any better way that would be greatful.

Here is my flow,

ConfirmPIN.js

```
 import { insertUser, deleteUser } from '../../../databases/schemas';

 savePin = (userPIN) => {   
    const newUser = {
      id: 1,
      userName: 'Here goes the user name',
      pin: userPIN
    }
    deleteUser(1).then().catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
    insertUser(newUser).then().catch((error) => {
      alert(error);
    }); 
  }
```

schemas.js

```
export const userSchema = {
    name: USER_SCHEMA,
    primaryKey: 'id',
    properties: {
        id: 'int',
        userName: 'string',
        pin: 'string'
    }
}

const databaseOptions = {
    path: 'retailApp.realm',
    schema: [ userSchema, appDataSchema],
    schemaVersion: 0 //optional
    //SHOULD I BE ADDING THE KEY HERE? IF SO HOW CAN I PASS THE KEY SET BY THE 
    //USER
}

export const insertUser = user => new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
    Realm.open(databaseOptions).then(realm => {
        realm.write(() => {
            realm.create(USER_SCHEMA, user);
            resolve(user);
        });
    }).catch((error) => reject(error));
});

export const deleteUser = userID => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Realm.open(databaseOptions).then(realm => {
        realm.write(() => {
            let userToDelete = realm.objectForPrimaryKey(USER_SCHEMA, userID);
            realm.delete(userToDelete);
            resolve();
        });
    }).catch((error) => reject(error));
});
```

securityUtils.js

Code to get the base64Encoded to be the KEY (Not tested how it works yet)

```
export const getBase64Encodedpin = pin => {
    var utf8 = require('utf8');
    var binaryToBase64 = require('binaryToBase64');

    var text = pin;
    var bytes = utf8.encode(text);
    var base64Encoded = binaryToBase64(bytes);
    return base64Encoded;
}
```

I want to be able to pass this key to schemas.js when opening the database, can you suggest on how I will be able to do that.

Thanks
R

Comment: looking for same !

Answer (score 0):

Here Retrieve your key from secure location or create one like below...

```
var key = new Int8Array(64);
```

Add Encryption Key in the schema

```
export const userSchema = {
        name: USER_SCHEMA,
        primaryKey: 'id',
        properties: {
            id: 'int',
            userName: 'string',
            pin: 'string'
        },
       encryptionKey: key, // add Your Pin/key Here
    }
```

Add key in databaseOptions

```
const databaseOptions = {
    path: 'retailApp.realm',
    schema: [ userSchema, appDataSchema],
    schemaVersion: 0, //optional
    encryptionKey: key, // add Your Pin/key Here
}
```

After searching I implemented this ,